# Documentation on the content place holders in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am looking for some kind of documentation on all the content place holders which are used in a 2010 SharePoint Master Page. I would like to know which place holders are overridden by and the controls they render. For example, I think the "PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" renders SharePoint groups + categories in a blog site.

i think it will be helpful if there is a list of all the controls and what they render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2009/12/21/list-of-all-possible-content-place-holders-of-sharepoint/